# Kubernetes cluster setup process in Docker Desktop on Windows 10 machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I have installed Docker Desktop in my windows 10 machine. And I am running the Linux Containers. I have enabled kubernetes. I am able to run hello-world docker image.

Now I need to setup a cluster environment in my machine, with one master node and 2-3 worker nodes.
As I can see master node is already setup, I need to setup worker nodes with it and deploy my microservices out there.

Please let me know the process on how to do the setup. I have checked on internet, but I could not find a very clear cut steps to perform the same.

Below is my current configuration :

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   16m
docker            Active   15m
kube-node-lease   Active   16m
kube-public       Active   16m
kube-system       Active   16m


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    master   17m   v1.16.6-beta.0


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl get pods
No resources found in default namespace.


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   x.x.x.x    <none>        443/TCP   21m
```

And below are my version information :

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
 Kubernetes:
  Version:          v1.16.6-beta.0
  StackAPI:         Unknown


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:26:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:18:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi nodes cluster [isn't supported](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3342) by Docker Desktop and it seems like they don't have any plans to support. This solution is meant for simple and small workloads.

I understand that you may want to simulate more complex workloads and for that I suggest you to take a look on [Kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind).

[This guide](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Kubernetes-Multi-Node-Local-Clusters-kind.php) can lead you through the process.